# Unmatch specific word between some symbols

Tags: c#, regex

I'm matching all the words with 2-5 letters which are either surrounded by a space, comma or `-`
with this regular expression

```
(([A-Za-z]{2,5}(?=[ \.-]))|((?<=[ \.-])[A-Za-z]{2,5}))
```

For example with this input

```
9-13 and 14-18
9-13 and.14-18
9-13 and-14-18
```

the word `and` will be always matched.
What I'm unable to achieve is to specify a list o words that should be not matched whatever the preceding and the next chars are.

For example I would like to specify that the word `und` and the word `ind` should not be matched no matter what is the previous or next symbols.

Comment: (?<=[ \.,-])(?!und\b)(?!ind\b)[A-Za-z]{2,5}(?=[ \.,-]) 
You can add as much as words as you need. Btw, you said comma but the list used to have period instead...

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\b(?![ui]nd\b)(?:[A-Za-z]{2,5}(?=[ .-])|(?<=[ .-])[A-Za-z]{2,5}\b)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?![ui]nd\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not `ind` or `und` directly to the right
- `(?:` Non capture group, match either

  - `[A-Za-z]{2,5}(?=[ .-])` Match 2-5 chars A-Za-z and assert either   `.` or `-` to the right
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=[ .-])[A-Za-z]{2,5}\b` Positive lookbehind, assert either   `.` or `-` to the left and match 2-5 chars A-Za-z followed by a word boudnary
- `)` Close non capture group

Note that you don't have to escape the dot in the character class.

[image]

Comment: @Wyck I have added a break down of the pattern.